# Cloud Firestore & Swift - Retrieve Document & assign fields to variables for processing

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have successfully retrieved the contents of a single document using get() but I can't seem to figure out how assign the fields to variables.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

```
let docRef = db.collection("ask").document(uid!)

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> Document data: `["q1": 1, "q2": 1, "q3": 0, "q4": 0]`

All of the values are boolean, true or false.

How can I assign the fields in the document to variables so that I can execute code based on the users answers:

```
var q1 = [?]
if q1 == false {
    //false code
} else {
    //true code
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend this way:

```
let docRef = db.collection("ask").document(uid!)

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")

        let data = document.data()

        let q1 = data!["q1"]! as? Bool ?? true

        if q1 == false {
         //false code
        } else {
        //true code
        }
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly but I am now having an issue where the if then statement only executing the else clause but I am working on it.  You solved getting the fields into the variables and I confirmed that worked via print command.

Comment: I got it.  This worked perfectly.  You solved getting the fields into the variables and I confirmed that worked via print command.  Thank you very much.